# Is it normal to get 14 MB images from UIImagePicker?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an iOS app which gets images from the camera with `UIImagePickerController`. Here is my code;

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!){

    imageTaken = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("camera", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){

        var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;

        imagePicker.mediaTypes = NSArray(object: kUTTypeImage)
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else{
        imageTaken = UIImage(named: "potato")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("camera", sender: self)
    }

}
```

I realized the image sizes are higher than I would expect (14 MB). I need to send the images to my server. My questions are;

- Is it normal to have 14 MB images?
- **Should I attempt to compress** them before I send them to my server? What is the common approach here?

Comment: Yes. It's a perfectly normal. I did face issue to send 50 MB size images to server earlier. 14 MB is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First question:

That's absolutely normal for an 8 MP image. Keep in mind that if you take an image from the gallery, the user can pick even bigger images if she/he have stored them on the device.

### Second:

It is always recommended to compress images. But in your case i think you already compressed it to **JPEG** or **PNG** with the corresponding methods.

Anyway upload such an image is totally fine if you don't have any server restrictions.
There is no lossless method to shrink the size any further.

One is to scale the image down which may be appropriate if you don't need the full 8 MP resolution.
The other is to limit the color palettes (256 colors or less) but this will result in massive loss in quality and detail. This will only make it easier for the compression algorithms of PNG or JPEG to do their work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will scale the images down as you suggested.